# Add to an ICollection

Tags: c#, icollection

I am currently writing a C# project and I need to do unit testing for the project. For one of the methods that I need to unit test I make use of an ICollection which is normally populated from the selected items of a list box.

When I create a unit test for the method it creates the line

```
ICollection icollection = null; //Initialise to an appropriate value
```

How can I create an instance of this ICollection and an item to the collection?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`ICollection` is an interface, you can't instantiate it directly. You'll need to instantiate a class that implements `ICollection`; for example, `List<T>`. Also, the [`ICollection` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx) doesn't have an `Add` method -- you'll need something that implements `IList` or `IList<T>` for that.

Example:

```
List<object> icollection = new List<object>();
icollection.Add("your item here");
```

Comment: But List<object> does not implement ICollection. Boardy asked for an ICollection.

Comment: @Hungary1234 `List<object>` implements `IList`, which is a descendant of `ICollection`. So `List<object>` is also an `ICollection`.

Comment: The way @Donut wrote the comment makes me feel QED is required at the end of it.

Comment: @Donut Who told that " ICollection interface doesn't have an Add method". Did u see this link  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63ywd54z.aspx

Comment: @AtishDipongkor That link refers to the `ICollection<T>` interface, which is different than the `ICollection` interface. You are correct that `ICollection<T>` contains an `Add()` method; however, `ICollection` does not: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx

Answer (score 5):

```
List<Object> list = new List<Object>();
list.Add(object1);
list.Add(object2);
// etc...

ICollection collection = list;
// further processing of collection here.
```

Contrary to some comments, `IList<T>` does implement `ICollection`, at least as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you will have a collection of strings, then the code will be:

```
ICollection<string> test = new Collection<string>();
test.Add("New Value");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to inherit the `ICollection` interface into a new class before you can use it.

[How to implement ICollection](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307484)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a type that implements ICollection and from there make use of it in your testing.  A List or Collection would work for creating an instance of the object.  I guess another question would be what type are the items of the list box.  Adding items to the List or Collection is pretty trivial just using the .Add(...) method.

```
List<T> list = new List<T>();
list.Add(item_from_your_list_box);
list.Add(item2_from_your_list_box);
```

Is there something more specific you need to be doing with this collection?