# Many to many navigation property is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, many-to-many

I have these two classes in my EF 6 code-first model:

```
public class Category {

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength( 128 ), Index( IsUnique = true)]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}

public class Article {

    [DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity ), Key]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength( 128 ), Index( IsUnique = true )]
    public string ArticleName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

I have this code in my data access layer to create a new article:

```
public Article AddArticle( string articleName, int[] categoryIds ) {
    if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( articleName ) )
        throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( articleName ), Properties.Resources.ArticleNameWasNull );
    if ( categoryIds == null )
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(categoryIds), Properties.Resources.CategoryIdsAreNull );

    using ( var context = new ArticleContext() ) {
        var article = new Article {
            ArticleName = articleName
        };
        foreach ( var category in context.Categories.Where( c => categoryIds.Contains( c.CategoryId ) ) )
            article.Categories.Add( category );
        context.Articles.Add( article );
        context.SaveChanges();
        return article;
    }
}
```

When I call this method, I get a `NullReferenceException` on the line in the `foreach` loop that adds the `Category` object to the `article.Categories` collection.

Obviously the `Categories` collection isn't initialized in the call to `new Article()`.  What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add to an ICollection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808744/add-to-an-icollection)

Answer (score 1):

You can't add an item to a null collection. You need to initialize `article.Categories` as a new collection.

```
article.Categories = new List<Category>();

foreach ( var category in context.Categories.Where( c => categoryIds.Contains( c.CategoryId ) ) )
    article.Categories.Add( category );
```

Alternatively add it where you are creating the object:

```
var article = new Article {
    ArticleName = articleName,
    Categories = new List<Category>()
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I realize that I need to instantiate the collection. I just didn't know what type of object to instantiate, since `ICollection` is an interface, not a class, and can't be instantiated.

Comment: @TonyVitabile you can use `List` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808744/add-to-an-icollection

Answer (score 1):

To avoid that kind of exception I always initialize the collection properties in a empty constructor:

```
public class Article 
{
   public Article()
   {
      Categories =new List<Category>();
   }
   //...
}
```

Comment: So a `List` will work? It doesn't have to be a `DbSet` or some other type of collection?